# SQLAlchemy filter always returns false

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a simple player entity:

```
__tablename__ = 'player'

_id = Column('id', SmallInteger, primary_key=True)
_nickName = Column('nick_name', String)

def __init__(self, nickName):
    self._nickName = nickName

@property
def id(self):
    return self._id

@property
def nickName(self):
    return self._nickName.decode(encoding='UTF-8')

@nickName.setter
def nickName(self, nickName):
    self._nickName = nickName
```

when i do:

```
players = session.query(Player).filter(Player.nickName=='foo')
```

and i print the `players` var i got this:

```
SELECT player.id AS player_id, player.nick_name AS player_nick_name
FROM player
WHERE false
```

Obviously, when I add `.first()` at the end of the session query, the result is `None`.
I have tried with `filter_by()` and get the same result.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Can I ask why are you creating properties instead of using columns directly?

Comment: If you really need to use properties, check [`synonym`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/mapper_config.html#sqlalchemy.orm.synonym), [`synonym_for`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/declarative.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.synonym_for) and [hybrid](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) extension.

Comment: @Audrius because it's the easiest way I found to fix an encoding problem. If you have an idea for this I would remove the getter/setter (I'm on windows). EDIT: Eevve answer fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using `@hybrid_property` *will* fix this in the general case, you shouldn't need to be decoding manually at all.  Just set the column type to `Unicode` instead of `String` and, assuming your server plays nice, you should correctly get back a `unicode`.

You also don't need the `id` property at all.

So all you should need for this class is:

```
class Player(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'player'

    id = Column(SmallInteger, primary_key=True)
    nickName = Column(Unicode)
```

(Both the column names and `__init__` arguments can be generated automatically.)

If there's some reason your database isn't handling Unicode correctly, well, that's a different problem that we'd love to help you fix.  :)

Comment: This works perfectly (both `Unicode` and `@hybrid_property`). Thanks. I manually specified column name because the field is named `nick_name` and the 'property' `nickName`. For the `__init__` part, it means that I don't need to define this method to have the behavior of my current `__init__`?

Comment: Python variables and methods are usually named `with_underscores` anyway, so why not just call it `nick_name`?  and yes, the declarative extension will generate an `__init__` for you that takes keyword arguments, so you can say `Player(nick_name=u'martinqt')`

Comment: That's because I'm new to python but I did C++ and PHP so I think I still have some old habits. Thanks for the advice, I'll try to do so for my next project.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use regular `@property`s as query parameters. Use a [`@hybrid_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/mapper_config.html#using-descriptors-and-hybrids) instead:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

@hybrid_property
def nickName(self):
    return self._nickName.decode(encoding='UTF-8')

@nickName.setter
def nickName(self, nickName):
    self._nickName = nickName
```

This makes `Player.nickName` (so on the attribute on the class) useful in SQL expressions.